# How to solve SSL_ read() returning -1

Tags: sockets, openssl

I'm using `SSL_read()`, transmission will return -1 at a certain time:

```
#define BUFSIZ 1024
dbuf = static_cast<char*>(malloc(BUFSIZ));`
int i = SSL_read(ssl, dbuf, BUFSIZ);
```

The `ssl` here has been initialized normally. No problem.

At this point, the return value of `i` is -1, and then I use `SSL_get_error()`:

```
int sslerr = SSL_get_error(ssl, i);
```

The following error becomes `write: No error`:

```
write: No error
write: No error
write: No error
```

The obtained `sslerr` value is 5. The document shows that this value means `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL`.

What is the cause of this parameter, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The cause of SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL is that a system call failed. To find out the reason why it failed it helps to look at errno which shows the error from the last system call. See also [the documentation for SSL_get_error](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_get_error.html):

> SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL
> Some **non-recoverable, fatal I/O error** occurred. The OpenSSL error queue may contain more information on the error. For socket I/O on Unix systems, **consult errno for details**. If this error occurs then no further I/O operations should be performed on the connection and SSL_shutdown() must not be called.

Typical reasons are that there is some loss of connectivity, either initiated by the peer or some broken connectivity in between. There is usually nothing one can do against this, instead one need to somehow recover from such connection loss. How such recovery can be done depends on the specific application.